# How to sort an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
Persoane = []
Nume = gets
Persoane.push Nume.split(",")
puts Persoane.sort
```

I am trying to get an user to input carachters that get split into substrings which get inserted in an array, then the program would output the strings in alphabetical order. It doesnt seem to work and I just get the array's contents, like so:

```
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Ruby> ruby "c:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Ruby\ruby-test.rb"
Scrie numele la persoane
Andrei,Codrin,Bradea
Andrei
Codrin
Bradea
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Ruby>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of your use of `push`. Let's assume that you define the constant `Nume` by

```
Nume='Andrei,Codrin,Bradea'
```

Then, `Nume.split(',')` would return the Array `['Andrei', 'Codrin', 'Bradea']`. When you do a `Persoane.push`, the whole array is added to your array `Persoane` **as a single element**. Therefore, `Persoane` contains only one Element, as you can verify when you do a

```
p Persoane
```

If you sort a one-element array, the result will also be just that one element - there is nothing to sort.

What you **can** do is using `concat` instead of `push`. This would result in `Persoane` being a 3-element array which can be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this :

```
Nume = gets
puts Nume.split(",").sort
```

or in 1 line

```
array = gets.chomp.split(",").sort
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need use constants here

If you don't need keep user input and use it somewhere, you can just chain methods like this

```
persons = gets.chomp.split(",").sort
```

Comment: As extraneous whitespace is likely unwanted on the individual names, I would suggest either mapping `&:strip` on the resulting `Array`. If you do that, the call to `#chomp` is unnecessary. Either that or `.split(/\s*\,\s*/)`

Answer (score 0):

For something a little different, let's not split at all.

```
people = gets.scan(/[^,]+/).map(&:strip).sort
```

This will avoid problems like multiple commas in a row yielding empty strings. Of course, you could also avoid that with:

```
people = gets.split(/\,+/).map(&:strip).sort
```